# Plesk for windows backup with wrong name if file names are non-Latin

Tags: iis, plesk, plesk-onyx

when i make a backup with Plesk on my windows server 2019, the generated zip file contains wrong file name for all non-English file name files as per attached image

[image]

and when i try to restore site does not work due to invalid file name
any suggestions for a solution??

i use latest version with windows server 2019,

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Culture and UICulture to Latin, and then set the enableClientBasedCulture property to true.

[image]

Comment: the issue in plesk backup exe as i think

Comment: How do you know that the problem is with plesk backup exe? If it is on plesk backup exe, this problem will also occur when running locally.

Comment: i tried all of this but i found that it only uncompressed correctly when it's done by the same Plesk server that created it, if i downloaded or transferred the file to another server it's not work and the result as the image above even with setting Culture and UICulture to Latin